# How do I setup RabbitMQ with JMS and AMQP 1.0?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, jms, amqp

I need to send messages to RabbitMQ through AMQP 1.0 and receive them with @JmsListener in Spring Boot. I've discovered there are two specific plugins for RabbitMQ that add support for AMQP 1.0 and JMS.

The JMS plugin is meant to be used with RabbitMQ's JMS Client library but on the AMQP 1.0 github they say that SwiftMQ Java Client is the one that works properly.

What I don't understand is, what do I need to use to fulfill the above requirements? How do I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the [Qpid JMS client](https://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/index.html) library. It implements JMS so it will integrate with Spring JMS and it speaks AMQP 1.0 over the wire so it will work with RabbitMQ + [AMQP 1.0 plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0/blob/v3.7.x/README.md).

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond earlier. I'd already tried Qupid, basically doing everything like in the official RabbitMQ JMS Client tutorial but didn't succeed. There were no errors. The program just stopped responding and didn't want to exit until I killed the process. Changing Qupid to JMS Client (i.e. using AMQP 0-9-1) worked perfectly but I need it to work with AMQP 1.0. So, no success.

Comment: Why would the RabbitMQ JMS client tutorial apply to the Qpid JMS client? Those are different clients.

Comment: The tutorial only includes setting up a ConnectionFactory bean. All I did was change the  RMQConnectionFactory to JmsConnectionFactory. They are both JMS clients and are supposed to provide the same API. In that sense, not so different

Comment: Fair enough. A quick web search indicates that it should work (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54323253/unable-to-send-messages-with-qpid-jms-and-rabbitmq-creating-amqpfixedproducer)). Without additional details it's impossible to say why it is not working for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll try it out. I would gladly provide additional details and probably wouldn't even have created this question if I had them. No errors, no messages. But the question you linked seems to be very similar to my case

Comment: Did you turn on any debug logging on either the client or the broker?